# broken intellisense in razor views in Orchard CMS

Tags: visual-studio, orchardcms

All the views I open on a clean install of Orchard CMS show tons of red squiggly errors under calls to methods that are somewhere defined in Orchard.

Sample methods:

- Display
- HasText
- Style
- SetMeta
- T

and so forth.

The web.config in this theme (thememachine) does have this defined: `add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"`

Let me add that it is a *huge* let-down to have to work entirely with dynamic, not just as an add-on, but as a solid foundation everywhere. Problems like this (no intellisense for most of what you need to do with the models and with Orchard commands in your views!) say it all. Do we thus get no / little intellisense in working in Orchard views?

In any case, the main question is: are such IDE errors (not errors on compilation) what everyone sees, and is there nothing to be done about it?

Comment: Maybe Orchard is not the CMS for you. Yes, it uses dynamic a lot, which is not for everyone.

Comment: Okay, I take that to mean that this is the behavior everyone has. I'm sorry to be a spoiler, and I do respect very much the reason Orchard went the dynamic route, to compete on the main (dynamic-based) foundational points with WordPress/Drupal.

Comment: The Orchard cheat sheet (http://sebastienros.github.com/CheatSheet/) comes in handy for this concern.

Comment: Please put that cheat sheet answer as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Orchard uses dynamic types a lot what you're seeing is not because of that. From the members you listed actually only Display is dynamic so you should get full IntelliSense and of course no errors for them.

What you experience is most possibly a general issue with Razor IntelliSense on your machine. Try researching "Razor IntelliSense not working" and you'll get some pointers. The possible problems I've encountered are the following ones:

- If you're using VS 2010 check that only MVC 3 Tooling is installed. If you have MVC 2 Tooling installed, uninstall it.
- If you're using a pre-release version of VS 2012 like the RC upgrade to the released version.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Pro, Update 1. So you are saying you get intellisense for these methods? The other answers seem to have indicated there wouldn't be any... I'll wait for others responses, would be glad if this answer were the truth.

Comment: Then this should work but as I said Razor IntelliSense does tend do go wild sometimes.
Yes, there is IntelliSense support for these methods, except for Display. Actually there are only three dynamic types you'll encounter in templates: Display (shape display method and factory), New (shape factory) and Model, if you don't use a statically typed model.

Comment: It never seemed to work for me, but I'll assume this is somehow the answer. I did realize it seemed odd, because some of those commands seemed to be non-dynamic, as you are saying, but anyways, maybe someone else will share here down the road how they get razor intellisense running correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 2013.  But I do get IntelliSense with VS 2012.